# How can I get and return the image from the firestore database

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a disneyplus clone with react and redux, i am able to store data on firestore and get to the react app. But however the card image is not updating.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { selctMovies, selectMovies } from '../features/movie/movieSlice'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

function Movies() {

    const movies = useSelector(selectMovies);

    return (
        <Container>
            <h4>Recomended for You</h4>
            <Content>
                { movies && movies.map((movie) => {
                    console.log(movie.cardImg);
                    <Wrap>
                        <img src={movie.cardImg} />
                    </Wrap>
                })
                }
```

But i can get image url when I do `console.log();` like this,

[image: in the log I can see the details]

**My code is like that**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You don't have return in the map callback function.

2- You should use key in map function.

3- You should use alt in images.

Try this

```
{   movies && movies.map((movie, index) => {
        console.log(movie.cardImg);
        return (<Wrap key={index}>
            <img src={movie.cardImg} alt="Card image" />
        </Wrap>)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the separate component for image and i hope your problem will got solve.